# Sharp and natural in the same bar when key already has a sharp

Tags: piano, notation

These pieces are from Victor's piano solo by Danny Elfman (from Corpse Bride by Tim Burton):

### Fragment 1

[image]

### Fragment 2 (lower stuff is in bass clef)

[image]

Here I want to know what keys on piano keyboard are red notes? My believe is that in the 1st fragment: **upper D is E4 (white key)** and **lower D is E2 (white key)** and in the 2nd case it is **D4-sharp** (black key)? Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, accidentals are never added to the key signature. D# means D# regardless of the key.

Comment: Why then to write a sharp sign in the first case? There are no naturals in that bar.

Comment: Because there was a D natural earlier in the measure, and the notator is just being extra careful that the player doesn’t accidentally keep playing D natural in the other octaves. In the first case, the #s aren’t technically necessary, but helpful. In the second example the # is necessary because the preceding natural is in the same octave. @LRDPRDX

Comment: "Extra clear" confused me =)

Comment: Pat is correct.  Double sharps, when called for, have their own notation: either two sharp signs ##, or a symbol which looks like a bold "x" **x**.

Answer (score 1):

You have all D#'s in red in both fragments due to the #. Those will be black keys.

The natural on the D in fragment 1 is up an octave (on the 4th line of the staff) and won't effect the D# below (just above middle C) but they give you a courtesy/reminder sharp to be extra clear.